# Image from device path not shown

Tags: flutter

I have downloaded a file to  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().
Then I have inserted the file path to a SQLite database.

In this case the file is a png file, and I need to show it on a screen.

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
Container(color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Image.file(File(${snapshot.data![position].path})),
                                  alignment: Alignment.center
```

)

I am geting an exception:

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path=//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2663D60-9BEF-4FFF-9287-BFD3CE6EF8BE/Documents/AgdsBeviewlogomodesto.png
```

I have checked if the path from the downloaded file is equal to the path from the SQLite item value, and  both are equal.

Downloaded file path print output:

```
flutter: path al archivo descargado /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2663D60-9BEF-4FFF-9287-BFD3CE6EF8BE/Documents/AgdsBeviewlogomodesto.png
```

SQLite path value :

```
path en docs:  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2663D60-9BEF-4FFF-9287-BFD3CE6EF8BE/Documents/AgdsBeviewlogomodesto.png
```

I have also tested putting that path as text directly into

```
Image.file(File("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2663D60-9BEF-4FFF-9287-BFD3CE6EF8BE/Documents/AgdsBeviewlogomodesto.png"))
```

and it works.

I don´t find the reason for not showing the image when using the value `snapshot.data![position].path`, knowing that it is the same value.

Answer (score 0):

In the exception, I can see that there is a leading `/` sign in the path which might be the problem.

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path=//var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2663D60-9BEF-4FFF-9287-BFD3CE6EF8BE/Documents/AgdsBeviewlogomodesto.png
```